# Validating Cordova project error

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

When validating my, simple, application I run into the following error:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'engine'. One of '{"http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":name, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":description, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":icon, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":author, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":license, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":content, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":feature, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":preference, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":access}' is expected. config.xml  /csam.test/www  line 31 XML Problem
```

This is my config.xml file, which was automatically  generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id="csam.test" version="1.0.0">
    <name>csam test</name>

    <description>
        Authentication application for CSAM.
    </description>

    <author href="#" email="">
        ZeeSteen
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />

    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" />
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />
        <param name="wp-package" value="BarcodeScanner" />
        <param name="id" value="cordova-plugin-barcodescanner" />
    </feature>


<engine name="android" version="4.0.2"/></widget>
```

Now this was all generated by by Eclipse/Cordova itself, and I'm not quite sure how to resolve the issue. I made sure the Android 4.0.2 engine is correctly installed.